# Filtering records not present with specific conditions in another table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a table (let's call it `extra_info`) in MySQL that has various extra information/labels on user accounts:

```
account_id / data_key 
11 / 'test' 
11 / 'blah' 
12 / 'coupon a' 
12 / 'coupon b' 
15 / 'whatever' 
18 / 'test'
```

And so on.

I am building reports on other tables but need to filter out records that are present in the extra_info table as 'test'.

So in the example above, records 1-10, 13-14, 16-17 are fine because they are not in extra_info, 11 needs to be filtered out (it is 'test'), 12 is fine (but obviously just need to have it once even though is has 2 labels, 15 is fine (not 'test'), and 18 needs to be removed.

I have done this with subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
    -- filter out test labels 
    a.id NOT IN (SELECT ei.account_id 
                 FROM extra_info AS ei 
                 WHERE ei.data_key = 'test')
```

This does its job, however, I have a suspicion that a regular join would have worked faster. What's the right syntax for it?

If I just join and filter out the ones with data_key='test', #11 would still be there - so this is not a solution. Grouping by account_id will probably has performance implications and basically same impact as the current code, right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

One option would look something like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM account a
  LEFT JOIN extra_info ei ON ei.account_id = a.id AND ei.data_key = 'test'
 WHERE ei.account_id IS NULL;
```

This might seem counter-intuitive, since "obviously" er.account_id is never actually `NULL` sitting at rest in the table, so I'll explain:

The `LEFT JOIN` of course means all rows from `account` and only the matching rows from `extra_data`... and by "matching rows" we mean those having an identical account_id and a value of 'test' in data_key.

Every row in a result set has, at some point during execution, either a value (or a `NULL`) for every column from all tables, even if those columns aren't listed in the `SELECT` list... so, in a `LEFT JOIN` where the table on the right has no corresponding rows, the columns in the result set that "came from" the right-hand table are `NULL`... so, WHERE ei.account_id IS NULL filters out the rows with a value for ei.account_id (the ones with matching account_id and 'test' in data_key) leaving you with a result set containing the rows that you want.

If it's not apparent now, it makes more sense when you remember that the `WHERE` clause is not telling the server which rows to find in this case... it's specifying which rows not to eliminate.

Now, if you need other data from `extra_info` in your report, you will need to [left] join that same table again in your query with different aliases in addition to ei in order to pluck out the other values.

@ypercube's advice on indexes still stands... in the case of the query in the question, an index on (data_key,account_id) would probably be more useful, since the subquery isn't correlated to anything in the outer query, while in the `LEFT JOIN` query, this index would be what you'd want:

```
[UNIQUE] KEY(account_id,data_key)
```